# Can't see output of GUI after process complete and ran

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I made my code successfully with no errors. However, when I run file, it gives a weird output to look at an oracle site instead of my output. How do I look at my results?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
public Frame() {
    //Create first Panel == p1
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 5, 5));

    p1.add(new JLabel("Input first number: "));
    p1.add(new JTextField(8));
    p1.add(new JLabel("Input second number: "));
    p1.add(new JTextField(1));
    p1.add(new JLabel("Results: "));
    p1.add(new JTextField(8));

    //Create second Panel == p2
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 2, 2));
    p2.add(new JButton("Add"));
    p2.add(new JButton("Subtract"));
    p2.add(new JButton("Multiply"));
    p2.add(new JButton("Divide"));

    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
    add(p1);
    add(p2);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.setTitle("*****Calculator*****");
    frame.setSize(450, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
} //end Frame Class
```

The weird output is:

> --------------------Configuration: --------------------
>   Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>             (to execute a class)
>     or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>             (to execute a jar file)
>   where options include:
>      -d32     use a 32-bit data model if available
>      -d64     use a 64-bit data model if available
>      -client      to select the "client" VM
>      -server      to select the "server" VM
>      -hotspot     is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
>                     The default VM is client.
>   and so on....

Comment: How do you run it, what platform is this (is it a Mac?), and can you please describe the "weird output" in more detail? What is the Oracle site in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `import java.awt.*;` There is a class `java.awt.Frame` which would interfere with your `Frame` class.

Consider renaming Frame class to something else. Also, please post the exact error/output.

Good luck.

Comment: I changed my class name to a different one. It seemed like the keyword  Frame was making the error.
Thanks!